# How to populate a jQuery Mobile list view of cities from Open Weather Map API?

Tags: json, api, jquery-mobile

I am trying to write a very basic jQuery Mobile app that will allow someone to select a city and view the current temperature using the OpenWeatherMap API. The data I want to use will be returned as json.

As per the landing page I can see that doing the query explicitly with the city is fine...

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk

But what I am unable to find is how do I query the API to simply return all the cities, which will then subsequently allow me to populate my list view, then allowing the user to see the temperature.

I have read some people talking about using a 'callback', but I am unable to see how this would help.

I have written a basic app previously, but again, that was using a fixed location, where the user didnt have to select it, so I never ran into this problem before.

I am having problems posting my code, but will attempt to post it later this eve.

Any pointers/tutorial links would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to contact them via email to get the latest list of countries.